# Is there anything equivalent to setImageResource for buttons?

Tags: android, button, android-listview, android-adapter, custom-adapter

I am creating a custom adapter so that I can put a button in a listView. I was putting it in just like I would an image and then I got to this line of code in the tutorial:

```
button.setImageResource(current_item.getButton_id());
```

I tried changing it to `setButtonResource`, but there is no method for that.
Thanks for any help.
I want it to look like this where there is a listview with a textview and a button. I got the text put in just fine, but I can't figure out how to get a button in ther listview.

[image]

This is my adapter:

```
private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SchoolsListClass>{
public MyListAdapter() {
    super(searchResults.this, R.layout.da_item, mySchools);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //Make sure we have a view to work with (may have been given null
    View itemView = convertView;
        if (itemView == null){
            itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.da_item, parent, false);
        }
    //Find school to work with
        SchoolsListClass currentSchoolsListClass = mySchools.get(position);
    //Fill the view
    //school name
    TextView schoolText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_schoolName);
    schoolText.setText(currentSchoolsListClass.getSchool_name());

    //subscribe/unsubscribe button
    Button button = (Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_subscribeButton);
    button..setImageResource(currentSchoolsListClass.getButton_id());//This is the line of code I am having trouble with. I want it to do exactly what it is doing for images, but use buttons instead of images.
    return itemView;
}
```

SchoolsListClass:

```
package com.parse.starter;

public class SchoolsListClass {
private String school_name;
private int button_id;


public SchoolsListClass(String school, int button){
super();
this.school_name = school;
this.button_id = button;



}


public String getSchool_name() {
    return school_name;
    }


    public int getButton_id() {
    return button_id;
        }
}
```

school_results.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/schoolListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

da_item.xml:(sample for items in my listview)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/itemLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_schoolName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/item_subscribeButton"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/item_subscribeButton"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:text="Central Wisconsin Christian School"
        android:textSize="@dimen/school_name_size" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/item_subscribeButton"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Are you saying that the button is not appearing in your listview at all, using this code?

Answer (score 4):

the equivalent is

```
button.setBackgroundResource(int resid);
```

Comment: That method is only for drawable resources, but I would like one for a button. That is the idea of what I would like it to do, just for buttons instead of images.

Comment: otherwise if you have an adapter that works with buttons, that would work too

Comment: Sorry  I don't get you... Do you want to set an Image as background for your button?

Comment: I just want to put a button in a listView, but in the tutorial I was following, they used an image, so the `setImageResource` didn't work because I was using it on a button, so how do you get a button into a listView?

Comment: set a color as background for your button. For instance button.setBackgroundResource(R.color.RED);

Comment: I see what does getButton_id return?

Comment: It is just using the default buttons that i put in the listview layout . I need it to put different buttons with unique id's on the listview. And it returns 0x7f060002, a button that says subscribe on it.

Comment: that id has to be an id of a Resource inside res/drawable otherwise it would not work

Comment: By the way, I don't have enough rep points to talk in chat, so please don't enter the conversation into chat.

Comment: Are there any methods that allow you to do the same thing just with a button instead?

Answer (score 0):

you can use but it is debricated in new API

```
button.setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

Comment: I am developing for api levels 8-17, so I would like to use methods that aren't depricated.

Comment: Hi sunil,
Doesn't setBackgroundDrawable just change the picture of the button?
If so, I still have a problem because I need that every button on the list will have a different functionality. Do you have any recomendation how to do this?